# Using class and property names as output in JSON

Tags: json, api, servicestack

I have this DTO:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then i have a route in servicestack that return a list of this DTO.
Method signature looks like this: `public IList<Post> GetAllPost()`

When getting result from this route my json look like this:

```
[3]
    0:  {
        Id: 2
        Message: "itworks1"
        CreatedDate: "/Date(1367264995010+0200)/"
    }-
    1:  {
        Id: 3
        Message: "itworks2"
        CreatedDate: "/Date(1367265002050+0200)/"
    }-
    2:  {
        Id: 4
        Message: "itworks3"
        CreatedDate: "/Date(1367265006767+0200)/"
}
```

However i would like the JSON output to look like this:

```
posts
    post:  {
        Id: 2
        Message: "itworks1"
        CreatedDate: "/Date(1367264995010+0200)/"
    }-
    post:  {
        Id: 3
        Message: "itworks2"
        CreatedDate: "/Date(1367265002050+0200)/"
    }-
    post:  {
        Id: 4
        Message: "itworks3"
        CreatedDate: "/Date(1367265006767+0200)/"
}
```

Is this possible with the servicestack serializer?

Comment: That would be illegal JSON. You cannot have more than one member with the same name.

Comment: Then how about the root node? Is it possible to manually name it?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your response in an object:

```
public class PostListResponse
{
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
...
public PostListResponse GetAllPosts()
```

Then your json should look like this:

```
{
    "posts":[
         { 
             "id":4,
             "message":"intworks3",
             "createdDate":"/Date((1367265006767+0200)/" 
         },
         { 
             "id":5,
             "message":"intworks4",
             "createdDate":"/Date((1367265006767+0200)/" 
         },
         ...
    ]
}
```